# Jquery dialog on dialog is working in firefox but not working in Chrome .Can Any bdy suggest change to be done to make the below snippet work?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

```
function searchHSCodePopUp(){
        var appname = "${ctx}";
        var url = location.href; // entire url including querystring - also: window.location.href;
        var baseUrl = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/', 14));
        baseUrl = baseUrl + appname;
        var token = "<c:out value="${TXN_TOKEN}"/>";
        var selectedColumn=document.getElementById("select").value;
        var enteredValue=document.getElementById("value").value;

        var finalUrl=baseUrl+"/filter/cttOwnerHsCodePopup?TXN_TOKEN="+token+"&column="+escape(selectedColumn)+"&value="+escape(enteredValue);

        hscodeDialog.dialog("close");
        hscodeDialog=$("#ownerHsCodeDialog").dialog({
            width: 600,
            height: 500
        }); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:finalUrl,
            secureuri:false,
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                    $('#ownerHsCodeDialog').html(data);

            },
            error: function(data,status, error){

            return false;
            }
         });
    }
```

Comment: remove from ajax request secureuri:false, async: false,

Comment: It,s Not working ,Is any thing else that can be added to code??